# Open external navigation app with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, navigation, external

I have a phonegap jquery app, I want to create Navigation Event.
I have coordiates \ address of location and I want to use appls like Google Nav\Waze\Glympse and others nav apps to open a new navigation to the destination.

Example:
I have coordinates of "Test 5" street in Los Angeles,
Click on the Adrress will launch the Navigation App and Take me to there (outside my application).

```
<a href="#">Test 5, LA</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#">43.2342,-70.4234</a>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it but create "href" to [Geo Link](http://geouri.org/)

work simply with "saddr" and "daddr" values just great!

Answer (score 0):

**geo:** href doesn't work in phonegap 3x , it only works in phonegap 2x only for showing location and search not for direction. 
Solution for open google map from phonegap 2x and 3x :

For Navigation -
window.open("google.navigation:q=23.3728831,85.3372199&mode=d" , '_system');

For Search - 
window.open("geo:0,0?q=pizza" , '_system');

Read Here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents